# Clear or Select the kendo grid cell on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo  grid - with hours column for multiple weeks (I am using clienttemplate to display it)
I also have an editor template to edit this columns. I have given edit mode as Incell
Now my requirement is to select the cell on click of the cell. I have tried :

```
function edit(e) {

    var input = e.container.find("input");      
        input.select();       
}
```

and

```
var currentDataItem = e.sender.dataItem(this.select());
```

but no use. Please help.

Comment: Your  e.container.find("input").select();  code will work. See http://jsfiddle.net/f186xsm0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help...
I have used the below code and it is working

```
    var input = e.container.find("input");
    input.focus(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
     input.select();
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: {
    type: "json",  
    pageSize: 10,
    serverPaging: true,
    transport: {
        read: "http://whatever"
    }
},
selectable: "cell",
pageable: true,
columns: ["ProductID", "ProductName"],
change: function() {
      var dataItem = this.dataSource.view()[this.select().closest("tr").index()];
      alert(dataItem.UnitPrice);
}
}
```